# Creating and managing Apple Developer Account for a company

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, accounts

As a freelancer, I now have to create an Apple-Developer-Account for the client's company. Because the Dev-Account is always connected to an Apple-ID, I need to create an Apple-ID with personal information as well.

How can I create and manage those Accounts properly in terms of personal information and verification, because a phone number, and maybe an Apple device, have to be connected as well. Do I create those accounts and change the phone number at the end, or how is that done properly?

Thanks!